# Schengen visa with cancelled UAE visa

Tags: germany, schengen-visas

I have valid Schengen visa for Germany mid of January next year. But my problem is my company is closing and my UAE visa will be cancel this month. Is it possible for me to travel to Germany with my valid schengen visa with a UAE cancelled visa?

Comment: Could you explain why you think your UAE visa might be relevant to entering Germany?

Comment: I was thinking if there will be problem here in Dubai immigration?

Comment: will you not be leaving before your visa expires?

Comment: After my cancellation i wilI have 30 days grace period.. then that time I will leave. Some are saying that I will have problem in Dubai immigration. Is that true?

Comment: if you're leaving within an official grace period I'd expect it to be fine: that's what a grace period means. But I'm no expert on UAE, so don't rely on my guess. I'd suggest editing your question to make the exact circumstances clear (currently it sounds like you're worried about whether you'll be allowed in to Germany, not whether you'll be allowed out of Dubai). Try to include: date of travel, date of expiration of UAE visa, and any details about the grace period you mention. If you've been working in UAE long-term, [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) may be a better fit

Answer (score 4):

Your UAE visa being canceled has no effect on your Schengen visa.  You can freely travel to Germany as long as your Schengen visa is valid.

Comment: There will be no problem in Dubai immigration?

Comment: Not unless you overstay in Dubai

Comment: No. After they cancel me I will go to Germany. It’s possible right?